# Search in the List Item Using C#

Tags: c#, list, linq, linq-to-objects

I have comma separated Id values like this: `3,4,5,7` and this differs for each records in the table.

Now from the configuration settings there are specific values like: `3,4`

I need to have code that will select only the records that match with the config values : `3,4`

Comment: Please add sample code with data to query. Then tell us which records should be selected.

Comment: @user1941025: We need sample code, please :-)

Comment: One specific thing for the code sample: your question is tagged linq to objects; but you mention records in a table. The answer (which I expect you'll need) will be different for linq-to-objects and linq-to-sql; so best to make sure that we're answering the right one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string.split` to convert a string of comma separated values into a list of individual values.

Then you can use linq to find all the values from one list that are also in the other.

```
var results = tableValues.Where(t => configValues.Contains(t));
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach element, you split it and then you search your keys.
Try this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private static List<string> lstStr = new List<string>
    {
        "1,2,3,4", 
        "3,4,5", 
        "3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
    };

    private static string[] search = new[]{"3", "4"}; // "3,4".Split(',')

    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach(var el in lstStr.Where(x => SearchFunction(x, search)))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(el);
        }
    }

    private static bool SearchFunction(string listItem, string[] search)
    {
        var hashSet = listItem.Split(',').ToHashSet();
        return search.All(hashSet.Contains);
    }
}
```